# How do I set the column width of some column width in datatables

Tags: html, css, datatables

This is my [data table](https://hattricknz.github.io/datatables_example2).

I can't seem to control the width of any of the columns:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
```

I have tried various methods [here:](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth)

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "autoWidth": false
} );
```

And [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

Without success.**Can anyone advise me on how I can manually control the width of some individual columns?** I am hoping it can be done using existing method in datatables.

Note: I will post a fiddle if I get a chance. 
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/7bh7w2tu/) - It is not exactly the same, but if my understanding is correct, I should be abloe to control the column width here:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My experience is that [**`columns.width`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) mostly is suitable for relative intents, i.e "I want this column to be relatively larger". There is a lot that can inflict on each column width, and even if you carefully target each column with an exact percentage that add up to 100 you end up frustrated.

If you want exact, precise column width definitions there is no way around hardcoded CSS :

```js
table.dataTable th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20px;
  max-width: 20px;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

table.dataTable td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20px;
  max-width: 20px;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/6eLg0n9z/**

Comment: tks, for my ref, you have to work on each column(th and td) like this `table.dataTable th:nth-child(3) ... table.dataTable td:nth-child(3)` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6eLg0n9z/1/)

Comment: @HattrickNZ, you only have to target the `<td>`'s if they are wider than the `<th>`'s and vice versa. I mean, you just need to make CSS for the necessary.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
#table-foo td:nth-child(3),
#table-foo td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 5%;
  max-width: 5%;
}
```

worked for me, you specify columns by rules separated by comma

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table like this that you target using `jquery datatable`,

```
<table class="table" cellSpacing="0" width="100%"
                               id="families-table">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th >Category</th>
                  <th><abbr title="Description">Des</abbr></th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

To control the width of a column, you can add this

```
<table class="table" cellSpacing="0" width="100%"
                               id="families-table">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                  <th **style="width: 250px;"**>Name</th>
                  <th >Category</th>
                  <th><abbr title="Description">Des</abbr></th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Adding `inline style` to a column would work perfectly. If you notice in the `dev tools`, you would see that `datatable` assigns `width` inline, so you apply anything using CSS file, it would be overridden. Adding `inline CSS` to columns work fine for me.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').removeAttr('width').DataTable({
            scrollY:        "400px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        columnDefs: [
            { width: 300, targets: 0 },
            { width: 100, targets: 0 },
            { width:100, targets: 0 }
        ],
        fixedColumns: false});

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

you can refer the http://jsfiddle.net/7bh7w2tu/10 for the same

Comment: tks, the min I can get the col width down to that way is 173px, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7bh7w2tu/11/)  by setting width to 10 `columnDefs: [
            { width: 10, targets: 0 },
            { width: 10, targets: 1 },
            { width:10, targets: 2 }
        ],` Can see the increase if I set the width to 500 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7bh7w2tu/12/). Also `targets: 0` refers to the 1st column...etc

Answer (score 0):

As I have 5 columns in my table, I can define each column width like this.

```
$('#example').DataTable({               
                "autoWidth": false,
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
                    { "width": "10%", "targets": 1 },
                    { "width": "50%", "targets": 2 },
                    { "width": "10%", "targets": 3 },
                    { "width": "20%", "targets": 4 },
                ]
            });
```

Keep "autoWidth" as false : This option disables the automatic column width calculation and sets the widths manually using the columnDefs option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).